# $X \in L_1$, $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ and $EX_n \to EX$. Prove that $X_n \xrightarrow{L_1} X$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ positive r.v. such that $X \in L_1$, $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ and $EX_n \to EX$. Prove that $X_n \xrightarrow{L_1} X$.

My attemp:
We have to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}E|X_n-X|=0$, then we can observe that
$$E|X_n-X| \leq E((X_n-X)1_{[X_n \geq X]})+E((X-X_n)1_{[X \geq X_n]}).$$

First we take this part: $E((X-X_n)1_{[X \geq X_n]})$. Then we have for hypothesis that
$$(X-X_n)1_{[X \geq X_n]} \leq X \in L_1,$$
and
$$P[(X-X_n)1_{[X \geq X_n]} > \epsilon] \leq P[X-X_n > \epsilon] \to 0.$$
Then when we take limit
\begin{align*}
        \lim_{n \to \infty} E((X-X_n)1_{[X \geq X_n]}) &= E(\lim_{n \to \infty}(X-X_n)1_{[X \geq X_n]})\\
        &= \int_{\Omega} \lim_{n \to \infty}(X-X_n)1_{[X \geq X_n]} dP\\
        &= \int_{[X \geq X_n]} \lim_{n \to \infty}(X-X_n) dP\\
        &= 0.
    \end{align*}

For the second expected value I do not know how to proceed. Is there other way or this way is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $L_1$ is a normed space, it is enough to prove that from every subsequence $(X_{n_k})_k$ we can extract yet again a sub-subsequence $(X_{n_{k_m}})_m$ such that $X_{n_{k_m}} \to X$ in $L_1$. Since any subsequence of sequence converging in probability converges in probability, and from sequence converging in probability we can extract a.s convergent subsequence, we can WLOG assume that $X_n \to X$ almost surely. Let us denote $Y_+ = \max\{Y,0\}$ and $Y_- = \max\{-Y,0\}$ (so that $Y = Y_+ - Y_-$). Note that from $\mathbb E[X_n] \to \mathbb E[X]$ and $\mathbb E[X-X_n] = \mathbb E[(X-X_n)_+] - \mathbb E[(X-X_n)_-]$ we get $\mathbb E[(X-X_n)_-] = \mathbb E[(X-X_n)_+] + r_n$, where $r_n$ converges to $0$. Hence $$ \mathbb E|X-X_n| = \mathbb E[(X-X_n)_+] + \mathbb E[(X-X_n)_-]= 2\mathbb E[(X-X_n)_+] + r_n.$$
Finally, due to non-negativeness, $(X-X_n)_+ \le X$ which is integrable, and since $X_n \to X$ a.s, we get $(X-X_n)_+ \to 0$ a.s, hence by dominated convergence theorem, $\mathbb E[(X-X_n)_+] \to 0$, so by above, $\mathbb E|X-X_n| \to 0$.

Comment: This is another way to prove it... I see. I used a variant of Pratt Lemma to the second expression, but this is a nice way to prove it. Thanks!